# Unable to convert map to list of object : dart

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read the bookmarked items in my app on page reload. The code queries the list of items previously bookmarked but unable to access the particular bookmarked index. What am I missing to map the objects correctly? please help!

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>_readfav() async {
   DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
   List<Bookmark> savedbk = [];
  final favs = await helper.queryAllRows();
  print(favs); // returns a map of favorite objects
   favs.forEach((row) => savedbk.add(Bookmark()));
   print(savedbk); // returns Instances of Bookmark
   print( savedbk[0].Ayah.toString()); // returns null-- this is the problem 

  return favs;

 }
```

**model class**

```
class Bookmark{

  int id;
  int Surah;
  int Ayah;
  int Juz;

  Bookmark();

  
  Bookmark.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {


    id = map[columnId];
    Surah = map[columnSurah];
    Ayah = map[columnAyah];
    Juz = map[columnJuz];
  }

  
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      columnSurah: Surah ,
      columnAyah: Ayah,
      columnJuz : Juz
    };
    if (id != null) {
      map[columnId] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the `forEach()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem comes from the fact that you are not using `row`

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>_readfav() async {
   DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
   List<Bookmark> savedbk = [];
   final favs = await helper.queryAllRows();

   favs.forEach((row) => savedbk.add(Bookmark())); <-- here

   print( savedbk[0].Ayah.toString());  

  return favs;

 }
```

Doing `favs.forEach((row) => savedbk.add(Bookmark()));` will only create a list of empty `Bookmark` instances.

Maybe you should use `favs.forEach((row) => savedbk.add(Bookmark.fromMap(row)));` based on your constructor

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem. Thank you!